# PDO+SQLite does not run multiple statements in one query?

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite, pdo

I'm running the following SQL using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)+SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE default_field_values (intfield INT NOT NULL, floatfield FLOAT NOT NULL, boolfield TINYINT NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX somename ON default_field_values (intfield,floatfield);
```

When feeding this to the [PDO::query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) method, a table gets created, but it ends up not having an index. When running the SQL via the sqlite3 CLI, it works as intended. The issue also does not occur when running MySQL.

Comment: Code that uses PDO helps.  Otherwise no one has anything to go on.

Comment: $this->mConn->query( $sqlString ); where $mConn is of type PDO. This is part of a third party farmework, so I can hardly paste all relevant code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) says:

> **PDO::query()** executes an SQL statement

And it did indeed execute an SQL statement.

PDO is not the CLI.
If you want to execute multiple statements, use multiple `query` calls.